# Why can’t I craft a sawmill or armor?

Tags: terraria-console

I have all of the materials for a sawmill yet it is not on the crafting menu. I also got 22 silver bars and no armor is on the crafting menu for silver.

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 5):

Here are the steps to craft a sawmill (to see if you have anything "wrong")

1. Get 10 wood blocks (to make work bench)
2. Make a [work bench](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Work_Bench) and place it down
3. Get 2 bars, 10 chains and 10 wood. (Get the bars from iron/lead ore, you'll need an [anvil](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Anvil) and and a [furnace](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Furnace), the chains will come from a bar (use anvil) and the wood from trees) If you need any help with getting any of these items, click the links for more information.
4. Go back to your workbench and with 2 bars (lead/iron), 10 chains and 10 wood in your inventory, and it should show up.

For more information [click here](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Sawmill)

Hope it helps ~Kingsley